# Pool de Conexões abre conexões mas não fecha depois!

Tags: java, postgresql

Estou enfrentando alguns problemas com  meu pool de conexões do postgresql com o java, em que ele é chamado pelos métodos do meus DAOs tranquilamente, mas não fecha depois que o método é executado, e isso atrapalha muito quando vou fazer alguma pesquisa e o banco fica lotado de conexões!

Vou mandar meu Pool e um dos DAOs:

```
package util;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource;

public class ConnectionFactory {
public static Connection connection;
private static javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource;

private static void createConnectionPool(){        

    PGConnectionPoolDataSource pool = new PGConnectionPoolDataSource();
    pool.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comercio_bd");
    pool.setUser("postgres");
    pool.setPassword("");
    pool.setPortNumber(5432);
    pool.setDatabaseName("comercio_bd");
    dataSource = pool;
}


public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{        

    if(dataSource == null){
        createConnectionPool();
    }

    if(connection == null || connection.isClosed()){
        //connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/alura", "postgres", "postgres");            
        connection = dataSource.getPooledConnection().getConnection();
        //connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    }

    return connection;

}


public void Close(){



} }
```

Vou mandar o DAO de Usuários:

```
    package DAO;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException; 
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import model.Funcionario;
    import model.Usuario;
    import util.ConnectionFactory;
    import view.TelaDeCadastro;
    import view.TelaPesquisas;
public class UsuarioDAO {
private Connection con = ConnectionFactory.connection;

public UsuarioDAO() throws Exception {

    try {
        con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void Salvar(Usuario u) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    if (u == null) {
        throw new Exception("Erro: Usuario não pode ser nulo!");
    }

    try {

        try {

            String sql = "insert into tbl_usuario (id_usuario, login_usuario, senha_usuario, fk_funcionario, flag_ativo)"
                    + "values (NEXTVAL('sequencia_usuario'),?,?,?,1)";

            //con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, u.getLoginUsuario());
            ps.setString(2, u.getSenhaUsuario());
            ps.setInt(3, u.getFuncionarioUsuario().getIdFuncionário());

            ps.executeUpdate();

            ps.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao inserir os dados!" + e.getMessage());
        }
    } finally {
       try { con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fachar conexão:"+e.getMessage(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    }

}

public ArrayList<Usuario> ConsultaU() throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<Usuario> listaU = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        try {
            //con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            TelaPesquisas tela = new TelaPesquisas();

            String sql = "SELECT usu.login_usuario, usu.senha_usuario, func.nome_funcionario, func.sobrenome_funcionario "
                    + "FROM tbl_usuario usu "
                    + "INNER JOIN tbl_funcionario func ON "
                    + "usu.fk_funcionario = func.id_funcionario "
                    + "WHERE usu.flag_ativo = 1 "
                    + "ORDER BY usu.login_usuario";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Usuario u = new Usuario();
                Funcionario f = new Funcionario();

                u.setLoginUsuario(rs.getString("login_usuario"));
                u.setSenhaUsuario(rs.getString("senha_usuario"));

                f.setNomeFuncionario(rs.getString("nome_funcionario"));
                f.setSobrenomeFuncionario(rs.getString("sobrenome_funcionario"));

                u.setFuncionarioUsuario(f);

                listaU.add(u);
            }
             ps.close();
             rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao buscar os dados dos Usuários!" + e.toString(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } finally {
        try { con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fachar conexão:"+e.getMessage(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    }
    return listaU;
}

public ArrayList<Usuario> ListarUsuarioNome(String login) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<Usuario> ListaU = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        try {
            String sql = "SELECT usu.login_usuario, usu.senha_usuario, func.nome_funcionario, func.sobrenome_funcionario "
                    + "FROM tbl_usuario usu "
                    + "INNER JOIN tbl_funcionario func ON "
                    + "usu.fk_funcionario = func.id_funcionario "
                    + "WHERE usu.flag_ativo = 1 and usu.login_usuario LIKE '%" + login + "%' "
                    + "ORDER BY func.nome_funcionario";
            //con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Usuario u = new Usuario();
                Funcionario f = new Funcionario();

                u.setLoginUsuario(rs.getString("login_usuario"));
                u.setSenhaUsuario(rs.getString("senha_usuario"));

                f.setNomeFuncionario(rs.getString("nome_funcionario"));
                f.setSobrenomeFuncionario(rs.getString("sobrenome_funcionario"));

                u.setFuncionarioUsuario(f);

                ListaU.add(u);
            }
            ps.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao buscar os dados dos Usuários!" + e.toString(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } finally {
        try { con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fachar conexão:"+e.getMessage(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
        System.out.println("Conexão ConsultaUsuariologin Fechada");
    }
    return ListaU;

}

public ArrayList<Usuario> ListarUsuarioCod(int cod) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<Usuario> ListaU = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        try {
            String sql = "SELECT usu.id_usuario, usu.login_usuario, usu.senha_usuario, func.nome_funcionario, func.sobrenome_funcionario "
                    + "FROM tbl_usuario usu "
                    + "INNER JOIN tbl_funcionario func ON "
                    + "usu.fk_funcionario = func.id_funcionario "
                    + "WHERE usu.flag_ativo = 1 and usu.id_usuario = " + cod
                    + "ORDER BY func.nome_funcionario";
            //con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Usuario u = new Usuario();
                Funcionario f = new Funcionario();

                u.setLoginUsuario(rs.getString("login_usuario"));
                u.setSenhaUsuario(rs.getString("senha_usuario"));

                f.setNomeFuncionario(rs.getString("nome_funcionario"));
                f.setSobrenomeFuncionario(rs.getString("sobrenome_funcionario"));

                u.setFuncionarioUsuario(f);

                ListaU.add(u);
            }
            ps.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao buscar os dados dos Usuários!" + e.toString(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } finally {
        try { con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fachar conexão:"+e.getMessage(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
        System.out.println("Conexão ConsultaUsuarioCod Fechada");
    }
    return ListaU;

}

public ArrayList<Usuario> ListarUsuarioFunc(String func) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<Usuario> ListaU = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        try {
            String sql = "SELECT usu.login_usuario, usu.senha_usuario, func.nome_funcionario, func.sobrenome_funcionario "
                    + "FROM tbl_usuario usu "
                    + "INNER JOIN tbl_funcionario func ON "
                    + "usu.fk_funcionario = func.id_funcionario "
                    + "WHERE usu.flag_ativo = 1 and func.nome_funcionario LIKE '%" + func + "%'"
                    + "ORDER BY func.nome_funcionario";
            //con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Usuario u = new Usuario();
                Funcionario f = new Funcionario();

                u.setLoginUsuario(rs.getString("login_usuario"));
                u.setSenhaUsuario(rs.getString("senha_usuario"));

                f.setNomeFuncionario(rs.getString("nome_funcionario"));
                f.setSobrenomeFuncionario(rs.getString("sobrenome_funcionario"));

                u.setFuncionarioUsuario(f);

                ListaU.add(u);
            }
            ps.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao buscar os dados dos Usuários!" + e.toString(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } finally {
        try { con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fachar conexão:"+e.getMessage(), "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    }
    return ListaU;

}}
```

Eu coloquei pra ele passar um sout pra verificar se estava chegando no finally, e estava, segue uma imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele executa o Finally que fecha a conexão, mas não retorna a mesma ao pool, segue uma imagem do meu comando `select * from pg_stat_actvity`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui Resolver! Tive que mudar totalmente o meu Pool, mas agora não está mais gerando uma conexão em cima da outra!
Segue o novo código:

```
package util;
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
public class ConnectionFactory {

static final BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
static Connection conn;

static{

    bds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    bds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comercio_bd");
    bds.setUsername("postgres");
    bds.setPassword("");
    bds.setMaxIdle(20);

}

public static DataSource getDataSource() {
    return bds;
}}
```

Eu mudei de pool para o DBCP, foi simples e rápido, nem precisa de arquivo xml pra configurar, ele faz tudo sozinho praticamente!
Para adicionar no DAO, basta fazer assim:

```
package DAO;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import model.Funcionario;
import model.Usuario;
import util.ConnectionFactory;
import view.TelaPesquisas;
public class UsuarioDAO {

private Connection con;
// no construtor da classe:
public UsuarioDAO() throws Exception {

    try {
        con = ConnectionFactory.getDataSource().getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }

}}
```